# Validation failed for one or more entities plus other error

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I'm trying to update my entity but it throw me this error:

*Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.*

This is the class that I'm trying to update.

public class Product : NotificationClass
{

```
private string name;
private int minStock;
private Category category;
public Product()
{
    Category = new Category();
    User = new User();
}


public int ProductId { get; set; }
[Required]
public string Name
{
    get { return name; }
    set
    {
        name = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
[Required]
public decimal SellPrice { get; set; }
[Required]
public int MinStock
{
    get { return minStock; }
    set
    {
        minStock = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
public int Remove { get; set; }
[Timestamp]
public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }

#region Relationships
public virtual Measurement Mesurement { get; set; }
public virtual Category Category
{
    get { return category; }
    set
    {
        category = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
public virtual User User { get; set; }
#endregion
```

}

I'm using this code to update:

```
using (MFSContext context = new MFSContext())
        {
            Product product = context.Products.Find(SelectedProduct.Id);

            product.Name = "Frank";

            context.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;


try
            {
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
            {
                Exception raise = dbEx;
                foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        string message = string.Format("{0}:{1}",
                            validationErrors.Entry.Entity.ToString(),
                            validationError.ErrorMessage);
                        // raise a new exception nesting  
                        // the current instance as InnerException  
                        raise = new InvalidOperationException(message, raise);
                    }
                }
                throw raise;
            }

            context.SaveChanges();
            LoadCategories();
        }
```

I saw other post where recommend to use a try catch but the problem is when I run the project throw me this exception "Password field is required", the problem is that i'm uploading the product entity... That atribute belongs to User entity so I don't understand.

PD: Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your product entity is creating a User entity. The User entity probably inherits from Identity class that requires a password. For inserts you will need to use a UserManager to add users, but since this is an update all you need to do is fetch the existing user attached to the product before updating:

```
Product product = context.Products.Include(p => p.User).Single(p => p.ProductId  == SelectedProduct.Id);
product.Name = "Frank";
context.SaveChanges();
```